# Fast method to convert List of Integers to int Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

What is the fast method for converting `List<Integer>` to `int[]` array, rather than using `mapToInt()`

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
list.stream().mapToInt(i->i.intValue()).toArray();
```